# How to disable axis labels in a PROC TEMPLATE's STATGRAPH block?

Tags: sas, sas-gtl

Suppose a SAS/GRAPH® GTL "DEFINE STATGRAPH" block has a "LAYOUT OVERLAY" block which produces a chart as shown below:

[image: SAS/GRAPH with an x-axis label]

How do I adjust the template to remove the label "mm_yyyymm"? I'm not seeing any options under [SERIESPLOT](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/grstatgraph/67882/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0828kpaepwjmrn1u5xko4cjlqln.htm) that would disable the label.

Comment: How exactly do you know when a llama has a headache?

Comment: Believe me, you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the type of layout.... but in all three, use a DISPLAY= option without a label tag.

**LAYOUT OVERLAY**

One can set the XAXISOPTS or YAXISOPTS options on the LAYOUT block:

```
layout overlay / xaxisopts=( display=(ticks tickvalues) griddisplay=on type=discrete )
```

**LAYOUT DATALATTICE or LAYOUT DATAPANEL**

This time it's the ROWAXISOPTS or COLUMNAXISOPTS options on the layout block:

```
  layout datalattice rowvar=x columnvar=y / rowaxisopts=(display=(ticks tickvalues)
```

**LAYOUT LATTICE**

The ROWAXIS / COLUMNAXIS statements can use the option inside their respective ROWAXES / COLUMNAXES block:

```
   rowaxis / display=(ticks tickvalues);
```